# CEF -Difference between CefBrowserView and CefBrowserHost

Tags: windows, google-chrome, chromium-embedded

I wonder what is difference between `CefBrowserView` base and `CefBrowserHost` base application.
When I research others Cef base application by spyxx , So many application don't have CefBrowserHost Window. But They have CefBrowserView.

Which one is recommended, `CefBrowserView` or `CefBrowserHost`?

`CefBrowserView` base application is composed as follows.

- CefWindow - CefBrowserView. ...

But `CefBrowserHost` base application is

- Windows Native Window - CefBrowserHost (as child)..

Answer (score 0):

`CefBrowserHost` uses a window that you give it.

`CefBrowserView` creates a window.

- If you embed CEF in an existing window in your app, use `CefBrowserHost`.
- If you create a new top level window, use `CefBrowserView`.

Comment: Can I get CefBrowserView Object from CefBrowserHost?

Comment: `CefBrowserView::GetForBrowser(browser_host->GetBrowser())`

Comment: When I call in `GetForBrowser` function in CefFocusHandler::OnGotFocus, It return `NULL`. That Browser was created by `CefBrowserHost`. Is it bug?

Comment: Not a bug, if a browser was not created by `CefBrowserView`.  Sorry, I misunderstood your first comment.